# Tensorflow 2 API: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm newbie in Tensorflow and I'm developing a notebook in Google Colaboratory.

On my first notebooks I got a message saying to update to Tensorflow v.2.

Now, in another notebook, I get the following message:

> The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

If I do that, am I using Tensorflow v2?
 I'm confuse because of the `v1` in `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph`.

All the error messages are:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:66:
>   The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:541:
>   The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4432:
>   The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform
>   instead.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4267:
>   The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d
>   instead.

I think I can't change that code on keras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still get some of these errors even if you use TF 1.1X, where X = 3/4/5.

Some of the libraries are already being deprecated, although available in TF 1.13/1.14/1.15. Note that TF 1.15 is the latest release for the version 1.X.

To ensure that you are using TensorFlow 2.0, use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

There are a couple of notable differences between the TensorFlow 1.X API and TensorFlow 2.X API; since you are a beginner, I would strongly recommend that you stick to the latest versions and take into consideration every deprecation warning, so as to use the newest updates.

The function `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()` is part of the TensorFlow 2.0 API: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph?version=stable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't asking that. Maybe, I haven't explained it well. I'm asking if `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()` is part of the Tensorflow 2 API. Thanks.

Comment: It is part of 2.0 API but some of them are going to be deprecated(not exactly sure of this exact function).

Answer (score 3):

It’s normal. As you mentioned in the question this warning returns to Keras. Keras is a high level api. It works with theano and tensorflow as backend for low level calculations. If Keras found any version of tensorflow or theano specific code executes that including this part:

```
tf.get_default_graph
```

In other side tensorflow doesn’t know who calls it. It throws a warning in future version `tf.get_default_graph` would be removed! Please be futuristic and don’t use it for code consistency.
It returns to Keras not your code. Keras published before tf v2.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pip install --upgrade keras` worked for me. It seems that the versions of keras installed with tensorflow was slighly outdated.